# How can I simply replace the colors using the color masks on this image and then save it? With RGBA channels as example

Tags: javascript, image, ffmpeg, colors, image-manipulation

So I got this GIF here:

[image]

As you can see, it has Red, Green and Blue in it. And it also has a full transparency in it. This was composed together with FFMPEG out of images that looked exactly like that.

Then, with FFMPEG I "decomposed" the RGB and Alpha channels using the filter "extractplanes".

The gallery of that, in correct order starting from up to down, can be found here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYP4C.jpg

I am not sure if this actually helps me or if I'm supposed to decompose them. Because apperantly now, after decomposing them, I'm supposed to modify them, but I'm not really sure how. It's like how do I modify the red channel that only has black and white, so all at the end, will match to the specified HEX color that I want it to be to.

Now, my question is. How do I exactly make the color changing happen? Can I do this simply with JavaScript? Is it possible to do with FFMPEG, if possible without ImageMagicks? Maybe a programming language where not much installation is needed to do that?

What I understood is that. These channels basically contain values from 0 to 255 with black and white. I think the "brightness" is that what 0 and 255. So something inbetween, would be like grey.

So basically, like we do (255,0,0) for red. In these channels, if I want red somewhere I need to put one fully white pixel on the red channel and on all the other channels, there has to be a fully black pixel.

That's the concept. Now is the question, how can I do this?

At the end I want to make it look like the colors this one has, as example:

[image]

This is from a game. So basically that's how it looks like in the game. And the game files only use these RGBA template sprites.

I asked a similar question here: [How to change colors of an image using RGBA and more channels independently of their color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717252/how-to-change-colors-of-an-image-using-rgba-and-more-channels-independently-of-t)

But somehow, I might didn't seem to explain it that well.

I made a thing here to test around with things. I guess that's nearly close, but the lines are kinda weird. jsfiddle.net/qsgazubk

Comment: Why do it outside ffmpeg? Use the [geq](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#geq) filter. Besides the docs, see some involved examples [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/24281/) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1486843/how-show-red-colour-border-at-edge-of-circle-video-cut-out-in-ffmpeg/1486856)

Comment: I actually want to do it with FFMPEG if it's simple. But I've been told that there are multiple examples, like also for javascript. As example, this: https://jsfiddle.net/1j7n6cqz/2/ but it's not yet really that what I want but it does some color operations, I found an example and modified it.

Comment: @Gyan but does this work on png's aswell? because geq is a video filter and png somehow bugged

Comment: For ffmpeg, an image is simply a video with 1 frame.

Comment: @Gyan yeah so what it does is that it somehow shows 1 frame that you maybe never see, except on the image thumbnail but the rest you don't for some reason

Comment: @Gyan I have this now https://jsfiddle.net/rv56jLs0/7/ wonder how I can get that to work in FFMPEG though.